# Two level embeded Template compilation error:memory exhausted

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

I got a compilation error:

```
[ 36%] Built target cgns
[ 36%] Building CXX object Common/ComputationalGeometry/CMakeFiles/CommonComputationalGeometry.dir/vtkParametricBohemianDome.cxx.o
[ 36%] Building C object ThirdParty/netcdf/vtknetcdf/CMakeFiles/netcdf.dir/libdispatch/daux.c.o
vtkWrapHierarchy-9.1: In /home/alex/workspace/vtk/Common/Core/vtkOStreamWrapper.h:108: memory exhausted.
make[2]: *** [Common/Core/CMakeFiles/vtkCommonCore-hierarchy.dir/build.make:281: lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vtk/hierarchy/vtk/vtkCommonCore-hierarchy.txt] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4078: Common/Core/CMakeFiles/vtkCommonCore-hierarchy.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 36%] Building CXX object Common/ExecutionModel/CMakeFiles/CommonExecutionModel.dir/vtkDataObjectAlgorithm.cxx.o
```

The line 108 of vtkOStreamWrapper is like this:

```
// Accept std::string without a declaration.
template <template <typename, typename, typename> class S> --- line 108
vtkOStreamWrapper& operator<<(const S<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>& s)
{
  return *this << reinterpret_cast<std_string const&>(s);
}
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: One single line of code couldn't be the cause of your problem. Please remember how to create a [mre].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude more code added

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: This functions is  burried in vtk library,it is called in many places